# PHP 5.5 Installer

Tags: php

I seem to be having a problem finding the PHP 5.5 msi file.  I have looked carefully on the PHP site and downloaded what I thought was the msi file, but it was just the dlls.

I have found installers for multiple items (WAMP), but I just need to upgrade my PHP from 5.3.6 to 5.5, not install Apache etc.

So does anyone have a link to the 5.5 msi?

The version I need is non thread safe 86 (ie, for Windows server 2008).

Greg

Comment: Have you considered [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)? (Albeit it's 5.4)

Comment: There are no official installer packages for php since 5.4. Well, I mean they might be discontinued, because there are no installers on [*windows.php.net*](http://windows.php.net). PHP 5.4 was implemented long time ago and it is probably should an installer for it, if there are no reasons to discontinue them. Try to install it manually. You may find manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php).

Comment: @MackieeE The OP explicitly stated "I just need to upgrade my PHP from 5.3.6 to 5.5, not install Apache etc."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no official installers (.msi's) for PHP, but there are binaries (they're what I use), which you can find here: **http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5**

Just extract it into some folder (say, C:\PHP), and add the bin folder to your PATH (if you want - most people do).

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was losing my mind there not being able to find them after finding many links on the internet stating they were available.

Comment: It's even stated in the install.txt that comes when you download the binaries. It talks about the msi, which is not there.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems actual again, the Windows binaries for PHP are available on SourceForge:

- php-7.0.9-nts-Win32-VC14-x86.zip
- php-7.0.9-nts-Win32-VC14-x64.zip
- php-5.6.24-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
- php-5.5.38-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
- php-5.5.36-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip

Link: [MSI package for installing non-thread-safe build of PHP.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpinstallermsi/)

NOTE: the title says MSI Installer, but they aren't, just only zip for manual installation.